# getUserMedia failed - Permission Denied on Lighting out using Twilio

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to make a video call using Twilio API with lightning component. In afterScript was successfully loaded. When we are try to access getUserMedia in afterScript load we are getting **Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined** error. we have checked script code in locker console, it's getting error on locker service issue. So we are planned to overcome this issue using **lightning out** concept. But unfortunately we are getting error **DOM Exception:Permission Denied** in lightning out.

*Here, we attach the sample code of what we are implementing.*

TwilioApp :

```
<aura:Application extends="force:slds">
    <iframe width="100%" height="450px" src="{!'/apex/VideoVf'}"/>
</aura:Application>
```

VideoVf :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.TwilioVideoJs}"/>
    
    <body>
        <div class="viewtable" id="videogrid">
             <div class="viewcontrol">
                  <div class="participantList" id="participant">
                  </div>
                  <div class="Primaryview" id="primaryid">     
                  </div>
              </div>
          <div class="yourView" id="urId">

          </div>    
        </div> 
    </body>
    
    <script>
        creatRoom();
    
       function creatRoom() {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: true
            }).then(function(mediaStream) {
                console.log("mediaStream created:::");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Could not connect to the Room:', error.message);
            });
            
        }
        
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Note : Directly working fine on Vf page.**

*If any one give solution, we will really appreciate*

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to resolve it ? 
I am having the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Lighting Component Issue. Most WebRTC Apis are not supported in Lockerservice. The only "workaround" change the of lightning component version to v.39.